# Error while using IF in inline Visual force page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I am using an inline IF expression for the value attribute of an <apex:column> inside an <apex:pageBlockTable>.

The code is as follows:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable var="mem" value="{!allMembers}">
            <apex:column value="{!mem.Name}" onclick="onClickMember('{!mem.Id}')" styleclass="{!IF(selectedMember.member.Id == mem.Id,'ui-state-active','')}">
            </apex:column>   

            <apex:column value="{!IF(mem.smoker__c == true,'Yes','No')}" onclick="onClickMember('{!mem.Id}')" styleclass="{!IF(selectedMember.member.Id == mem.Id,'ui-state-active','')}">
            </apex:column> 

            <apex:column value="{!mem.Eligible_Program__r.Name}" onclick="onClickMember('{!mem.Id}')" styleclass="{!IF(selectedMember.member.Id == mem.Id,'ui-state-active','')}">
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Plan Chosen"><apex:inputCheckbox /></apex:column>

   </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

The error thrown is:

> Visualforce Error
>
> Syntax error. Missing ')' Error is in expression '{!IF(mem}' in
>   component <apex:pageBlockTable> in page vf_plan_selection

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: The error is happening on for the following statement value="{!IF(mem.smoker__c == true,'Yes','No')}"

Comment: Is there any documentation about usage of inline Apex constructs in an visual force page?

Comment: is smoker__c definitely the name of the field in the members object, is it available to the page, and you are sure it is within this snippet of the VF page that the error is being generated?! (a good way to test would be to remove that evaluation and see if the page no longer generates this error)

Comment: Yeah I am very sure. There is no error seen if the line of code is removed. Also, if I give `value="{!IF(mem.smoker__c == true,'Yes','No')}}" ` (here I have given an extra `}` before the expression ends) the value is retrieved properly but appended by a '}'. The value seen on the screen if the smoker__c is true is 'Yes}' and 'No}' is seen when smoker__c is false. Weird! A very likely apex bug.

Answer (score 2):

The value attrbute of [apex:column](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_column.htm) needs to be an SObject field which its not in your example.

You need to change:

```
 <apex:column value="{!IF(mem.smoker__c == true,'Yes','No')}" onclick="onClickMember('{!mem.Id}')" styleclass="{!IF(selectedMember.member.Id == mem.Id,'ui-state-active','')}">
            </apex:column>
```

To something like this:

```
        <apex:column headerValue="Smoker">
            <apex:outputText value="{!IF(mem.smoker__c == true,'Yes','No')}"/>
        </apex:column>
```

**On a side note:**

If the `smoker__c` field is a boolean then there is no need for the `mem.smoker__c == true` comparison

Try changing this:

```
{!IF(mem.smoker__c == true,'Yes','No')}
```

To this:

```
{!IF(mem.smoker__c,'Yes','No')}
```

Comment: There is no limitation on using the '==' or '!=' operators on checkbox/boolean fields in the IF formula operator.

Comment: Yep. That'd do it! Good spot.

Comment: Tried this. Still get the same error.

Comment: Try removing the apex:column from the VF page to make sure the page saves correctly. Once that is done then add some text e.g. `<apex:outputText value="Test"/>`, verify that the text appears. Then try `<apex:outputText value="{!mem.smoker__c}/>` to make sure that appears. Then finally try `<apex:outputText value="{!IF(mem.smoker__c == true,'Yes','No')}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

> {!IF(mem}

It looks as like the error you've posted is happening outside of the code block you posted.

This is opening the IF statement with left paren ( and closing it with right bracket }, which does not happen in the snippet you posted.

Unfortunately Visualforce errors don't give you line numbers, so it's hard to find exactly there the error is.  I'd suggest looking in your page for a place where you're accidentally using a right bracket instead of a right parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header"></apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="Yes" rendered="{!mem.smoker__c}" />
    <apex:outputText value="No" rendered="{!!mem.smoker__c}" />
</apex:column>
```